# Jenkins - Error while pom use jar from local repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a Java project, say it's named `x` which have been installed to local maven repository.

Jenkins is configured to use the local Maven repository.

There is another project, say it's named `y` which works well in jenkins, until I added a dependency to use `x` project. When build `y`, it tips:

> [WARNING] The POM for xxx is missing, no dependency information available

and

> Failure to find xxx in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Seems jenkins will search remote server for the jar of `x` project, rather than check the local repository.

So, how can I fix that, thx.

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Matt My edited question is not a solution, because I still don't know what caused the issue. It's just an explanation for what happened, so I don't think it's proper to add it as an answer.

Comment: The "solution" you appended to your answer solves the problem asked in your question; so you should post it as an answer. Since it's unclear *why* it solves the problem, you can either ask a *new* question, or re-write (rather than just append to) your question to ask that.

Comment: @Matt The unclear part is the cause, because I already removed the dir, so I can't reappear it. The so called solution is just a normal pre-action for `maven` user to use jar from local repository. I think it's more proper to delete the question, but since other people might get the same issue, I just keep it there.